# Symfony2 Constraints\email not found

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints

I installed a email validator for a newsletter form in Symfony2. Locally everything works fine, but if I upload the whole folder to my webhosting i get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\email' not found in /home/donacico/public_html/spendu/donaci14/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Loader/AbstractLoader.php on line 64
```

My validation yml looks like this:

```
# src/Dbe/DonaciBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Dbe\DonaciBundle\Entity\Newsletter:
    properties:
        email:
            - email:
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
                checkMX: true

Dbe\DonaciBundle\Entity\Contact:
    properties:
        email:
            - email:
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
                checkMX: true
```

And here is the action of the create controller:

```
/**
     * Creates a new Newsletter entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request) {
        $entity = new Newsletter();
        $form = $this -> createCreateForm($entity);
        $form -> handleRequest($request);

        if ($form -> isValid()) {
            $em = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getManager();
            $em -> persist($entity);
            $em -> flush();

            $this -> get('session') -> getFlashBag() -> add('newsletterSubscribed', 'Thank you for subscribing!');

        }

        return $this -> render('DbeDonaciBundle:UnderConstruction:index.html.twig', array('entity' => $entity, 'form' => $form -> createView(), ));
    }
```

Also in the config.yml file I have validation enabled:

```
framework:
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

Any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: Keep in mind that although Windows' paths and PHP identifiers (class names) are case-insensitivie, Linux filepaths aren't. Change `email` to `Email` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work on a linux system its case sensitive.

```
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\email'
```

to

```
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email'
```

otherwise the autoloader can't find the file and the class.

Comment: Do I need an Entity called Email than?? Where do I need to put the use statement?

Comment: I don't where you have implemented your constraints ;) there are some posibilities to do that. Search for the contraint and change it.

Comment: I have it implemented in the Newsletter controller (use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\email;) but it doesn't make any difference if I write it case sensitive or not. Still the same error, i guess I have a understanding problem...
If you look at my code, is there something missing?

Comment: Have you cleared you cache? The Error says that he can't find the class and that is because its not correct. You should read the manual for constraints. You should implement the constaint in your Form type or in your yml file.

Comment: Here is my Form Code, it seams to be fine, no?
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;

class NewsletterType extends {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                  "required"=>true)
                  );
    }

Comment: And yes I cleared the cache a couple of times and I also read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It really was a error case of case sensitive, but I corrected the wrong one.

> ## src/DbeDonaciBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

```
Dbe\DonaciBundle\Entity\Newsletter:
    properties:
        email:
            -  Email :
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
                checkMX: true
```